# Replaces all words that are not wrapped in a span tag

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to replace all words not wrapped in a span tag to (space).
I've tried various ways, but so far not getting what I want.

The code that I wrote below is quite effective, but there are still many shortcomings.
For example if the lyrics are capitalized, they will not be converted to spaces.

So what's the best way to achieve this goal?

Here's the code I currently have:

**Update:**
On the second line, the capital letters aren't converted to spaces, so it's pretty messed up.

I want the result to be:       `Am            Em   C            G           C            G`

```html
<div class="chord">

abcd ef<span>Am</span>ghi jklmn op<span>Em</span>
Yes<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcDE<span>G</span>Fghijk
qrst<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcde<span>G</span>fghijk

</div>
```

```
$('.chord').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/a|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|<|>|\/|"|'|=|_|-|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0/g, " ")
    .replace(/ b| m/g, "  ")
    .replace(/\[ | \]|\( | \)|\[\(|\)\]| :|\nm|\nb|\n\n/g, "\n")
    );
});
```

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you want. What are you trying to replace the non-span-wrapped words with? Could you please [edit] your question to show an example of the result you want?

Comment: i've edited it, it's an example of the resulting error

Comment: I would walk the DOM. If you find a text node, check its parent. If it's a `span`, don't replace. If it's not, replace the text node with an equal number of space characters.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How does it work? i Do not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code simply goes through all of the child nodes of the `<div class="chord">` element and replaces text nodes with sequences of spaces of equal length to the existing string. Note this only works because the tree here is flat; a child of `.chord` is either a text node or a `span`. If either of those changes, the code will need to be more complex to accomodate.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.chord');
for (const kid of container.childNodes) {
  if (kid.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    kid.nodeValue = " ".repeat(kid.nodeValue.length);
  }
}
```

```css
.chord { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div class="chord">

abcd ef<span>Am</span>ghi jklmn op<span>Em</span>
Yes<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcDE<span>G</span>Fghijk
qrst<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcde<span>G</span>fghijk

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to get what you want in array check this:

```js
const chord = document.querySelector('.chord');
const span = chord.querySelectorAll('span');
const spanText = [];
span.forEach((item) => {
  spanText.push(item.innerText);
});
console.log(spanText);
```

```html
<div class="chord">

  abcd ef<span>Am</span>ghi jklmn op<span>Em</span>
  Yes<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcDE<span>G</span>Fghijk
  qrst<span>C</span>uvwxyz abcde<span>G</span>fghijk

</div>
```

Comment: but the space sign is missing here